# Strange literal when using non-ascii characters in string

Tags: python, unicode

I have the following test:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

def test_literals():
    test_cases = [
        'aaaaa',
        'ááááá',
        u'aaaaa',
        u'ááááá',
    ]
    FORMAT = '%-20s -> %2d %s'
    for data in test_cases :
        print FORMAT % (data, len(data), type(data))

test_literals()
```

Which gives:

```
aaaaa                ->  5 <type 'str'>
ááááá           -> 10 <type 'str'>
aaaaa                ->  5 <type 'unicode'>
ááááá                ->  5 <type 'unicode'>
```

I am surprised about `'ááááá'`. What kind of literal is that? It is no unicode, since it has no `u` prefix (and the type says `str`), but it is also not a normal ascii string.  I would like to know:

- What is it?
- Is it possible to get more information about a `basestring` object (`unicode / str`), appart from its type?
- How can I dump the bytes in hex?

Comment: `import binascii; print binascii.hexlify(b'aaaaa'); print binascii.hexlify(b'ááááá')`

Comment: `print repr(b'aaaaa'); print repr(b'ááááá')`

Comment: I have no `b'ááááá'`: I have `'ááááá'`.

Comment: @gonvaled: In Python 2, there's no difference.

Comment: standard ascii only goes up to 127. but characters are 8 bits. the character you show is in the 'extended' ascii range. afaik, what actually gets displayed for that character depends on the code page of the console, some python internals, etc.

Comment: I am surprised about the downvotes. Why? That is just actual code. I am doing nothing wrong, I just have a question about a real behavior of a piece of test code.

Comment: I don't quite understand the downvotes either, but maybe it doesn't show enough effort to understand the problem. For example, why are you wondering how it's not an ASCII string if you declared the script as UTF-8 encoded? Anyway, have a +1

Comment: Because I have found *nowhere* information about what happens when you define a string with extended ascii characters. It has always worked for me in the past, but now that I am solving lots of unicode related stuff in my code, I need to understand exactly how python internally defines these objects. It is stated in the documentation that `u""` literals are unicode, and that `""` literals are bytestring, but I have not seen anywhere explained what are `""` literals with extended ascii. I understand now that this creates a simple bytestring. Maybe this should be clarified in the docs.

Comment: Oooops. I have added another testcase to my test which makes things clearer for me now: bytestring `'αβγδ'`. Python accepts that (I thought it would complain), and is also a bytestring! So, if I understand this correctly, since the editor has already encoded this using `utf-8`, I can assume in my code that all string literals are encoded in `utf-8`, right? And all unicode literals can be encoded however I want to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. It's a UTF-8-encoded string. The fact that it's printing correctly shows that your terminal happens to be using UTF-8, too. Lucky you. That script would fail on a Windows box.
   How do I know this? You declared the script as being UTF-8 encoded, so Python will interpret the source code accordingly. When printing it, Python will send the raw bytes of the encoded string to the console. If that's set to the same encoding, you get the correct output. If not, you don't.
2. No. You need to know the encoding that is being used. Ideally, you control that yourself. In the real world, it's possible to make an inspired guess sometimes (see [chardet](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/chardet)), but you can't rely on this.
3. See @falsetru's comment.

All in all, if that confuses you, it might motivate you to switch to Python 3 where all this is much easier.

Comment: one more question. When declaring a unicode literal, the literal string is still encoded (in this case in `utf-8`, since that is the file encoding as defined at the top). But python will generate a unicode object out of that. Does that mean that python is automatically decoding during the parsing phase all unicode literals according to the file's encoding? I guess so, but I would need a confirmation to make sure I am getting this right.